# same sql in controller and in model has different result

Tags: php, laravel

i have a same sql but put one is put in model, one is put in controller, it return different result

put in controller (result = 2);

```
public function data() {

    $vendor_id = $this->getVendorId ();

    $menu = Menu::where('vendor_id', '=', $vendor_id)->get();

    var_dump(count($menu));

}
```

put in model (result = 1);

```
public function data() {

    $vendor_id = $this->getVendorId ();

    $menu = new Menu;
    $menu->getMenuByVendorId($vendor_id);

    var_dump(count($menu));

}
(in model)
 public function getMenuByVendorId ($vendor_id) {

     $menu = Menu::where('vendor_id', '=', $vendor_id)->get();


     return $menu;
 }
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code here

```
public function data() {
  $vendor_id = $this->getVendorId ();
  $menu = new Menu;
  $result = $menu->getMenuByVendorId($vendor_id); // assign result in a variable and then count
  var_dump(count($result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model change the data function to:

```
public function data() {
    $vendor_id = $this->getVendorId ();
    $menu = new Menu;
    $menu = $menu->getMenuByVendorId($vendor_id);
    var_dump(count($menu));
}
```